# How can I stop procedure #1 from displaying a success message when procedure #2 fails and raises an error?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have procedure #1 that calls procedure #2. When procedure #2 raises an error, it successfully displays a message about the error. However, procedure #1 still displays the message that the customer was successfully added to the database. How can I stop this from happening?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUST_TO_DB (pcustid number, pcustname varchar2) AS
err_range EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    if pcustid < 1 OR pcustid > 499 THEN
        RAISE err_range;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTID, CUSTNAME, SALES_YTD, STATUS) VALUES (pcustid, pcustname, 0, 'OK');
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA-20001:ERROR:DUPLICATE CUSTOMER ID');
    WHEN err_range THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA-20002:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID OUT OF RANGE');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV (pcustid number, pcustname varchar2) IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('----------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Adding customer. ' || 'ID: ' || pcustid || ' Name: ' || pcustname);
    ADD_CUST_TO_DB(pcustid, pcustname);
    dbms_output.put_line('Customer Added OK');
    commit;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
END;
```

> Actual result:  Adding customer. ID: 595 Name: Jeff Jeff
>   ORA-20002:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID OUT OF RANGE Customer Added OK
>
> Expected result: Adding customer. ID: 595 Name: Jeff Jeff
>   ORA-20002:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID OUT OF RANGE

Comment: Why have you chosen to catch exceptions and display a message, instead of letting the exceptions bubble up and naturally interrupt the calling flow?

Comment: I'm completing a task which has told me to do it exactly this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception in `ADD_CUST_TO_DB` is handled properly and procedure `ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV` even don't know about it.

You should either raise the error from the `EXCEPTION` block of the `ADD_CUST_TO_DB` procedure which will be handled by `ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV` or you can even set one OUT parameter to know the exact error in `ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV`.

Something like following will do the task for you. (Throwing exception from `ADD_CUST_TO_DB`)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUST_TO_DB (pcustid number, pcustname varchar2) AS
err_range EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    if pcustid < 1 OR pcustid > 499 THEN
        RAISE err_range;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTID, CUSTNAME, SALES_YTD, STATUS) VALUES (pcustid, pcustname, 0, 'OK');
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA-20001:ERROR:DUPLICATE CUSTOMER ID');
        RAISE; --add this
    WHEN err_range THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA-20002:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID OUT OF RANGE');
        RAISE; --add this
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
        RAISE; --add this
END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Easy solution! Unfortunately it doesn't produce the result that I want. My tasks requires me to only have the output: Adding customer. ID: 3 Name: Emma Jones
ORA-200012:ERROR:DUPLICATE CUSTOMER ID

But when I use raise, I get the extra text:
Adding customer. ID: 3 Name: Emma Jones
ORA-200012:ERROR:DUPLICATE CUSTOMER ID
ORA-00001: unique constraint (S102178938.SYS_C00320809) violated

Comment: That's because your exception block in ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV is catching the error a second time in its WHEN OTHERS section. You could catch it a second time there and do nothing, but I think it'd be simpler to just move all your error handling to ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV.

Comment: Perfect @kfinity, all you need is to move all exception handling code to your caller procedure

Comment: The exception handling can only be the way it is in my code. I can't move anything around. Anyway for me to fix this without moving stuff?

Comment: Yes - in ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV, before WHEN OTHERS, put `WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUST_TO_DB (pcustid number, pcustname varchar2) AS
err_range EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    if pcustid < 1 OR pcustid > 499 THEN
        RAISE err_range;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTID, CUSTNAME, SALES_YTD, STATUS) VALUES (pcustid, pcustname, 0, 'OK');
        dbms_output.put_line('Customer Added OK');
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA-20001:ERROR:DUPLICATE CUSTOMER ID');
    WHEN err_range THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA-20002:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID OUT OF RANGE');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV (pcustid number, pcustname varchar2) IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('----------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Adding customer. ' || 'ID: ' || pcustid || ' Name: ' || pcustname);
    ADD_CUST_TO_DB(pcustid, pcustname);
    commit;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you could get expected result

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUST_TO_DB (pcustid number, pcustname varchar2) AS
err_range EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    if pcustid < 1 OR pcustid > 499 THEN
        RAISE err_range;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUSTID, CUSTNAME, SALES_YTD, STATUS) VALUES (pcustid, pcustname, 0, 'OK');
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA-20001:ERROR:DUPLICATE CUSTOMER ID');
        raise;
    WHEN err_range THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ORA-20002:ERROR:CUSTOMER ID OUT OF RANGE');
        raise;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
        raise;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUSTOMER_VIASQLDEV (pcustid number, pcustname varchar2) IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('----------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Adding customer. ' || 'ID: ' || pcustid || ' Name: ' || pcustname);
    BEGIN
    ADD_CUST_TO_DB(pcustid, pcustname);
    dbms_output.put_line('Customer Added OK');
    exception 
    when others THEN 
    --dbms_output.put_line('Customer not Added OK');
    null;
    end;
    commit;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
END;
```